# Installing the Citrix Receiver doesn't install all of the required libraries and executables

Tags: citrix

[This](https://i.imgur.com/Owwf7aO.gifv) is what my installation directory looks like. But when I install the Receiver on a user's PC, they only get like 6 DLLs and the CDViewer.exe. Everything else is missing, so they can't open anything from Citrix.

His receiver installation was originally messed up. So I tried uninstall and re-installing, but it kept saying it was already installed. So I ran the cleanup utility and then installed it from the login prompt. Which didn't work. So I repeated the process and installed from http://downloadplugins.citrix.com/Windows/CitrixReceiverWeb.exe. That also didn't work, so I repeated the process once more and then installed from https://www.citrix.com/products/receiver/. But it also didn't work.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by running the Citrix Cleanup Utility, restarting, and then installing the LTSR Receiver.

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/windows-ltsr/receiver-for-windows-ltsr_4_9_1000.html#ctx-dl-eula